# ExternalInterface.addCallback does not work right

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have js code:

```
function onFlashReady() {        
    sendToAS("sit");
}

function callJS(value) {        
    onFlashReady();
    return "Hi Flash.";
}

function thisMovie(movieName) {
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
         return window[movieName];
     } else {
         return document[movieName];
     }
 }
 function sendToAS(value) {         
     thisMovie("FlashID").callAS(value);
 }
```

html:

```
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="850" Height="588" id="FlashID" tabindex="0">
      <param name="movie" value="BusFlex/BusProducts.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
         <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="BusFlex/BusProducts.swf" width="850" height="588">
      <!--<![endif]-->
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <div>
         <h4>Установите или включите Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
         <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
      </div>
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
         </object>
      <!--<![endif]-->
      </object>
      <script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <!-- swfobject.registerObject("FlashID"); //-->
      </script>
      </div>
```

and actionscript code:

```
protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
     flash.system.Security.allowDomain("http://mysite.ru");
     flash.system.Security.allowDomain("http://localhost");
     if(ExternalInterface.available)  
     {
          ExternalInterface.addCallback("callAS", fromJS);
     }
     ExternalInterface.call("callJS", "Hello JS!");
}
public function fromJS(str:String):void 
{
   ...
}
```

But it works in IE only. In FF this does not work. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is in your flash embed html, Mozilla browsers rely on the `embed` tag but you have `object` again.  Try using something like so within your object node:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="BusFlex/BusProducts.swf" width="850" height="588" allowscriptaccess="always">
</embed>
```

Comment: How does embed work in ie do you have to keep both the object and the embed tag? [Swfobject][http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/] has kept me happily unaware of this.

Comment: Yep you would keep both where the embed is just nested within the object.  I prefer swfobject too and overlooked that you are using its registerObject function.  Now I'm not quite sure the issue, are you certain document["FlashID"] is not null in FF?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!!! I was looking for an answer for two days!
This my new code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="850" height="588" id="FlashID" tabindex="0">
    <param name="movie" value="BusFlex/BusProducts.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />

    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <embed src="BusFlex/BusProducts.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="BusFlex/BusProducts.swf" width="850" height="588" allowscriptaccess="always" name="FlashID">

      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <!--<![endif]-->

      <!--[if IE]>
      <div>
        <h4>YCTAHOBUTE Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
      </div>
      <![endif]-->
     <!--[if !IE]>-->
     </embed>
    <!--<![endif]-->
  </object>
```